# Average memory used on a LAMP server

Tags: lamp

How much memory (RAM) would the average LAMP production server use, assuming little-to-no traffic, barebones except Apache2, PHP 5.3, MySQL5 installed and running?

Comment: How long is a piece of string?

Seriously, this is a really ambiguous question because it takes absolutely no consideration of configuration. Are you talking with no PHP software like Wordpress, Magento or such installed? How much data will MySQL have and will it be setup to use more memory and threads of the CPU it's running on? How many Apache threads? This can vary between installations.

Comment: I did mention "barebones except Apache2, PHP 5.3, MySQL5 installed and running". No wordpress, no Magento, no nada. Just wanted to know what the norm for a setup like this is because I'm seeing about 300MB used just running on idle with <10 visitors daily. Not sure if that's normal or not.

Comment: Barebones LAMP stack installed with defaults at 300MB is normal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My default is 4GB right now for all server roles because memory is cheap.  For a low usage server with hardy anything running using that software, you could probably get away with <1GB.  If you're that concerned about the cost of RAM, it will be worth your time to test your RAM usage.  Otherwise, just get 4GB and you're almost guaranteed to be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I really depends on usage but I run that lot in 240Mb without any problems. Is the 300Mb all processes or mostly disk cache and buffers? Linux will keep using memory for disk cache till it is all gone.